# Radio button in portlets view.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, portlet

Am new to portlet Programming.i have a portlet.In view.jsp of this portlet i have a form with textfield and two radiobuttons.i need to get the textfield value when i click on the radio buttons.also based on the text field value i have to retun a value to the view.jsp.

```
 PortletURL updateBookURL = renderResponse.createActionURL();
 updateBookURL.setParameter(
 ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME, "update");
```

Am try with this Action Url.and put in the onclick of `radio button(onClick="<%=updateBookURL.toString()%>)`.update is a function in portlet class.but it shoudnot go to the class.am using eclipse indigo withliferay 6.0
help me.thanks in advance

Comment: Check this - may be it will help: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/developing-a-portlet-with-multiple-actions

Answer (score 0):

For this I think you need to configure on click event on radio buttons and then using ajax call serveresource method of controller in return you send required values back to view and set accordingly

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="serveResourceURL" id="serveResourceURL"</portlet:resourceURL>
AUI().ready(
    function(A) {
        A.all('.radiobuttonClick').on('click', function(event){
            var checkboxObj = event.currentTarget;
            var textfieldValue = A.one('#textfieldId').val();       
            A.use('aui-io-request', 
                function(aui) {
                A.io.request("<%=serveResourceURL%>", {
                    autoLoad : false,
                    cache : false,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data:{'textfield':textfieldValue},
                    method:'POST',
                    on : {
                        success : function(event, id, xhr){
                            var response =  this.get('responseData');
                              console.log("response::"+response);
                            //set values accordingly
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            });
        });
    });
```

Let me know if you need more help